# QGIS - Zero values after joining .shp to .csv

Tags: qgis-3

I'm using Australian Bureau of Statistics (ABS) data to create thematic maps. Everything works fine when using POA (post code) data. I've created a .csvt sidecar file for the CSV. After the join I can make graduated and categorised maps fine.

I follow the same procedure for SSC data (suburbs) but after the join QGIS returns values of 0 for all fields when trying to make graduated maps. I use QGIS 3.x

Posctcode Screenshots:
Fields:[Postcode fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z72hI.png)
Attribute Table:
[image: Postcode Attribute Table]
Produces Map:
[image: Postcode MaP]

But for SSC:
Fields:
[image: SSC fields]
Attribute Table:
[image: SSC Attribute Table]
[image: Attribute]
Produces Zero Values:
[image: SSC 0 Values]

Comment: Do you see the values in the attribute table after joining? If not the join was not successful. There might be some differences in the join fields, like extra spaces.

Comment: Also, what column are you using to join the SSC data - SSC_CODE or SSC_CODE16? Do you get null results with either column? (Hopefully you are not using SSC_NAME...)

Comment: I am using SSC Code as SSC Code 16 is actually a completely different code. In saying that - I actually did try with both. Maybe as Heikki suggests there is some extra spaces (etc...) in one set of data -this would be unusual as it is all from the same source (ABS). Thanks for you input - it is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved.

Despite the values in the SSC_Code field in the .shp file and appearing identical to values in the SSC_Code field in the .csv , there was obviously something amiss in the data.

The .shp file also had a field SSC_Code 16 (which basically had the same values as the SSC_Code field but without the prefix 'SSC')

On the .csv I made a new column/field for SSC_Code16. Copy/pasted the SSC_Code values and used the find/replace function to remove the 'SSC' prefix from the values. I then updated the .csvt to include the new field. Once I created the join in QGIS - BINGO - everything worked! Happy Days!